# Inno Setup String literal too long insert BLOB into table

Tags: database, oracle, inno-setup, pascal

I'm trying to write a script by inno setup to insert a raw in a table which has a BLOB column and I don't know how to write my code correctly ,My database is Oracle and my Inno setup compiler version is 5.5.3 as well.Does anyone help me to find a solution?

This is all my efforts :

```
var
  Content: String;

try
     ADOCommand := CreateOleObject('ADODB.Command');
     ADOCommand.ActiveConnection := ADOConnection;  
     Stream := TFileStream.Create('D:\test.png', fmOpenRead);
     Count := Stream.Size-1;
     Stream.Seek(-Count, soFromEnd);
     SetLength(Buffer, 1);
     Content := '$' ;
     for Index := 1 to Count do
        begin
          Stream.ReadBuffer(Buffer, 1);
          Content:=  Content + (Format('%2.2x', [Ord(Buffer[1])]));
      end;
     ADOCommand.CommandText :='insert into TestBinaryTable(id, blobData) values(1 ,''' + Content + ''')';
     ADOCommand.Execute();
```

Comment: What DB is that?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl it's Oracle DB

Comment: OK, but you should edit your question to include this information, not post it in comments + You got two answers meanwhile, would you react to those?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you should prefix the raw data with `$`.

Remove this line:

```
Content := '$' ;
```